# Is there a difference among 'hay que', 'tener que', and 'deber'?

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, verbos, diferencias-entre-palabras

I understand that all of these:

- hay que
- tener que
- deber

are the Spanish equivalent of “ought to” or “must” or “should".

But I really need to know if there are any subtle differences in the sense they convey.
Also, are there any regional preferences?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre “haber que” y “tener que”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/37020/5481) Donde se explica mejor la diferencia entre "haber/hay que" y "tener que".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, those equivalences are not right, it *should* be:

- `Should` is the equivalent of `debería`.
- `Must` is equivalent of `deber`.
- `Have to` is equivalent of `tener que/haber que`
- `Ought to` is equivalent of `tendría que`

Those are the proper equivalences. I would not point any difference since I think they are quite similar in use. But I find that `ought to` is tricky when translating. Anyway, in general those are used in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in my [answer to another question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37021/24236), "**haber que**" (*hay que*, *habrá que*, etc.) are **impersonal** verb forms, which means that they do not have a subject. They express a general obligation and mean something similar to "it is necessary to...", as explained [on DLE](https://dle.rae.es/haber) (seventh meaning). For example:

- Hay que hacerse un test de COVID para poder entrar en España <sub>(*It is necessary to take a COVID test to be able to enter Spain*)</sub>

On the other hand, both "**tener que**" and "**deber**" are conjugated, i.e., they **have a subject**. They are used to talk about an obligation that applies to a specific person or group, and are equivalent to *have to*/*must*:

- Tengo que hacerme un test de COVID para poder entrar en España <sub>(*I have to take a COVID test to be able to enter Spain*)</sub>

Regarding the difference between "**tener que**" and "**deber**", DLE says about [deber](https://dle.rae.es/deber?m=form):

> 1. tr. Estar obligado a algo por la ley divina, natural o positiva. U. t. c. prnl. *Deberse a la patria*.
> 2. tr. Tener obligación de corresponder a alguien en lo moral.
> 3. tr. Cumplir obligaciones nacidas de respeto, gratitud u otros motivos.

and about [tener que](https://dle.rae.es/tener):

> 17. tr. Denota la necesidad o determinación de hacer aquello que expresa una cláusula posterior introducida por *que*. *Tendré que salir*.

This means that "**deber**" expresses obligations that are due to **moral**, **religious**, or **legal** reasons, or a **self-imposed** feeling of obligation (for example, due to gratitude). "**Tener que**" denotes an obligation due to **necessity** or **determination**.

As you might see, the difference between these two is small, and in many cases they are used interchangeably. You can say

- Debo estudiar más el año que viene

and interpret it as a self-imposed obligation, or you can say

- Tengo que estudiar más el año que viene

and interpret it as determination. While the version with "tengo que" sounds stronger (to me), there is a fine line between "self-imposed obligation" and "determination".

Comment: Buena respuesta, coincido con el matiz entre _deber_ y _tener que_. Sobre el formato, en [How should we format text?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2571/1674) bosquejamos una serie de pautas para dar un estilo más o menos canónico a las publicaciones. Una que me gusta (si bien no está explícitamente escrita allí) es poner `texto original <sub>texto traducido</sub>`.