# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "haber que" y "tener que"?

Tags: verbos, diferencias-entre-palabras, haber

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "haber que" y "tener que"? Por ejemplo, entre "había que tirarlo" y "tenía que tirarlo". La duda me ha surgido leyendo el poema de Júlio Cortázar llamado "Para leer en forma interrogativa".

> Has visto,
>  verdaderamente has visto
>  la nieve, los astros, los pasos
> afelpados de la brisa…
>  Has tocado,
>  de verdad has tocado
>  el plato, el
> pan, la cara de esa mujer que tanto amás...
> Has vivido
> como un golpe
> en la frente,
> el instante, el jadeo, la caída, la fuga...
> Has sabido
> con cada poro de la piel, sabido
> que tus ojos, tus manos, tu sexo, tu
> blando corazón,
> **había que** tirarlos
> **había que** llorarlos
> **había que**
> inventarlos otra vez.

Comment: Por si es útil, hay una pregunta preexistente (en inglés): [Hay que vs tener que vs deber](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5481)

Comment: ¿Puede decir "ella había que" en lugar de "había que"?

Comment: ¿de verdad tenemos la etiqueta [tag:haber]? :O

Comment: @Diego curiosamente, la respuesta a esa pregunta no dice nada sobre la diferencia entre "haber que" y "tener que"...

Comment: @wimi Ya ves. Creo que dice que ambas son la misma cosa ("Have to") y no explica ninguna potencial sutil diferencia entre ambas. Quizá por eso esas contribuciones tienen tan pocos votos. Quizá vendría bien una respuesta adicional en esa pregunta, o enlazar esta pregunta (y respuestas) en esa.

Comment: @Diego veo que ya has añadido un comentario en la otra pregunta. Eso pasa a veces: el [consultante](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/35514/24236) acepta una respuesta no muy buena, y entonces nadie quiere añadir más respuestas. En general creo que una respuesta que solamente proporciona traducciones no suele ser muy buena, porque muchas veces (como en este caso) la correspondencia entre los términos españoles y los ingleses no es exacta.

Comment: @Diego podría añadir una respuesta a la otra pregunta, pero sería básicamente una traducción de mi respuesta aquí, añadiendo también la diferencia entre "tener que" y "deber", que es, a mi juicio, bastante pequeña y probablemente dependiente de la región.

Comment: Sí parecen equivalentes. En casos así, y dado que la otra apenas tiene visitas (menos de mil en seis años), bien podrían _mergearse_ para que la señal de aceptado se pierda en la otra y aquí aparezca como respuesta normal.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' hmm no parece que se cumplan [los requisitos para *mergear*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158067/643262) (duplicado *exacto* y respuestas muy valiosas en ambas preguntas). En ese link también se recomienda que la operación de *merge* se aplique solo después de que la pregunta haya sido cerrada como duplicada. Yo sugeriría que si se consigue que la comunidad cierre una de las dos preguntas como duplicada de la otra, pensamos si queremos preservar las dos respuestas y mergeamos en caso afirmativo.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' si no se consigue ese cierre como duplicado en unos días, traduciré mi respuesta de aquí y la extenderé para responder completamente a la otra pregunta (si no lo ha hecho otra persona antes).

Comment: @wimi precisamente es para evitar la dispersión de la información. Si la otra pregunta (la pregunta solo) no tiene mayor relevancia, se puede marcar como duplicada de esta si esa respuesta no es demasiado útil (no mata demasiado, la verdad). Si la información que queremos preservar es la de la otra, como sugieres al decir que pondrías la respuesta allí, lo suyo sería marcar esta de aquí como duplicada de la otra. En cualquier caso, tener dos respuestas prácticamente equivalentes en dos preguntas parecidas me parece la opción más débil en el marco mental que deseamos (información centralizada).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' he añadido una respuesta a la otra pregunta, porque la otra pregunta abarca más (incluye también "deber"), y porque está en inglés. Se podría cerrar entonces esta pregunta como duplicada de la otra, que creo que tiene más sentido cronológicamente y también por lo de que la otra abarca más. Pero preferiría no hacerlo con el martillo: puedes iniciar la votación si estás de acuerdo.

Answer (score 6):

"**Haber que**" es una forma impersonal. Solo se conjuga en tercera persona del singular ("hay que", "había que", "habrá que"), y no tiene sujeto: no se puede decir "ella había que". En muchos casos, un sinónimo de "hay que" sería "es necesario" (véase acepción 7 [en el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/haber)):

- Hay que hacerse un test de COVID para poder entrar en España (=*Es necesario hacerse un test de COVID para poder entrar en España*).

"**Tener que**" es una forma personal: se conjuga en cualquier persona, y siempre hay un sujeto concreto (aunque con frecuencia se omita como ocurre normalmente en español). Véase acepción 17 [en el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/tener?m=form). Es equivalente a "deber" o "necesitar":

- Tengo que hacerme un test de COVID para poder entrar en España (=*Necesito hacerme un test de COVID para poder entrar en España*).